# z-index or opacity issue?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have this website http://wedessertmore.com that has some forms popup when you click on the top menu links. All works well on most browser, all but IE8 and IE9, where the popup text is showing blurred. I've tried various combination of z-index values for all the items. Can it be because of the opacity values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document has a CSS `#menu-container *` line 39 inside grid-layout.css file. In that css `filter:alpha(opacity=10)` is creating problem. Try removing it.